Visual studio 2022 keeps crashing
Visual Studio 2022 keeps crashing while opening.
I am working on project of ASP.NET Core API (.NET 6.0). Everything was working fine up until yesterday, but today when I tried opening the project, first it said project is incompatible, then I deleted the .vs folder from the project and opened the .sln in Visual Studio 2019. I was able to run the project, but not able to edit it because the project dependency is dot net6, which is not supported by Visual Studio 2019.
So, I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022 and installed it again, but now the IDE opens and I can see the project files, but it crashes after a few seconds. I can't even create a new project, the IDE crashes no matter what.
What more I tried:

starting IDE in safe mode
Renaming OnlineLicensing\VisualStudio file
running IDE as administrator


Does your project build on your CI server? There is a decent chance the solution or project file is broken, and you could try reverting to an earlier known good version.

If you create a new solution, will you be able to reproduce the issue? If still occurs, try repair the vs via vs installer. :)

I tried both of the things. issue still persists.

finally the issue is solved. first of all there was some issue with IDE for sure so i reinstalled the IDE but the issue was still there. the only thing that i need to do was to find the Services>ProjectName.API file, right click on it and then set it as a startup project and it worked. Thanks for the comments and answers, they helped too.

I have done a test on my side and also using ASP.NET Core API, but i was unable to reproduce the situation on my side.
Since you have tried to remove the .vs folder and repaired the VS, there are other solution that could solve this issue:

Update VS to the latest version.

Try to remove VS cache(navigate to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_xxxxxxxx\ComponentModelCache folder, backup and remove all ComponentModelCache folders), and test again.

Reset Visual Studio settings(run devenv /ResetSettings in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022).
Reinstall the ASP.NET workload from VS Installer > Modify > Workloads > uncheck the workload > Modify > check it again > Modify.

Try to run devenv /Log command in Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022, reproduce this issue and navigate to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ActivityLog.xml, open ActivityLog.xml file and check if there’s any detailed error message.

Also use Process Monitor to check the windows log:
Process Monitor



Maybe the log can give you a hint. Try to start VisualStudio from the developer command prompt like this:
devenv /log c:\temp\vs.log

In Visual Studio 2022: I used Extensions > Manage Extensions and updated several items that indicated as needing to be updated.  Closed and reopened Visual Studio and this problem went away.
